# Serialising a form data in jquery gives unnecessary symbols.How to avoid them?

Tags: php, jquery

Serialise() function in jquery adds unnecessary  symbols to the data.

In my script i'm doing serialize() in jquery .Then  sending this value to another php file through jquery ajax function as one of the parameter.Then inserting into database through queries.The variables are converting into unnecessary variables.Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

$params = $("#admit_order").serialize()

Actual Result : 1152%2BHidden%2BRidge
Expected Result : 115 Hidden Bridge

Answer (score 2):

You can  decode the serialised data by using decodeURIComponent().

```
  $params = $("#admit_order").serialize();
  decodeURIComponent($params);
```